# How can I resolve 1 of 2 same-model displays not working in a 3 monitor setup?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, amd-radeon, tv

TLDR: **3rd monitor shown in Display (Settings), but not audio/video. Audio does show in Sound (System Tray).**

### DXDiag

System:
[image: System Info]
Audio:
[image: Audio Info]
From DXDiag, I'm not certain which display is which, so here's all three:
[image: Display 1]
[image: Display 2]
[image: Display 3]

---

I just received a TV and am attempting to connect it as a 3rd monitor. I have gotten Display Settings to recognize it's existence, but neither audio nor video works through it.

I was thinking the issue was monitor 1 & monitor 3 being the exact same make, model, size, etc. So, I had a look around at the properties of each monitor in Device Manager. The "device instance path" of monitor 1 & 3 are different, so I'm not sure why it isn't displaying to monitor 3.

I also attempted disconnecting monitor 2 to see if it was an issue with the graphics card (Radeon RX 5700 XT), but, since each screens refresh rate is 59.xxx, I'm doubting that. Anyway, nothing was substatially different when having 2 vs 3 displays. I've attempted all display modes (single only, mirror, extend, 2nd single only; there's no 3rd single only option). I also attempted setting monitor 3 as main, but nothing changed and it timed out.

I was about to go to regedit to compare monitor 1 & 3, but thought I'd better ask experts before fiddling around in the registry. **So, does anyone here have any advice or have run into this before?** I'm in an odd situation wherein the PC is connected to 3 TVs, and I use AMD instead of NVDIA, so I'm unable to find any advice online that applies (though I still attempted some "fixes"—which were mostly obvious things in Windows Settings).

Oh! And this may be relevant, I'm also using two DisplayPort⇿HDMI adapters at the graphics card (monitor 2 & 3). I hadn't previously heard of passive vs active adapters, so I presume they are passive. But again, since I'm not using high refresh rates, I'm not sure how much impact that could have.

```
Windows 10
Emerson 60" [direct HDMI]
Toshiba (Japanese version) 42" (I think?) [DisplayPort⇿HDMI adapter]
Emerson 60" [DisplayPort⇿HDMI adapter]
Sapphire 21293-01-40G Radeon RX 5700 XT 8 GB
AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 3.7 GHz 8-Core.
```

Don't hesitate to let me know if you require more information.

Thanks so much~

Comment: Seems like monitor 3 doesn't work under any configuration - have you tried a different 3rd monitor, or have you tried monitor 3 on another computer? What are the resolutions?

Comment: Do each of the screens work if you ONLY connect them (1 screen at a time)? Try to use the adapter you originally used when connecting all three & the same video card port. Logic here is you confirm each screen & adapter works by itself. This may help understand if a certain adapter isn't working

Comment: Graphics card tech specs confirm it can support 4x screens: https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/21293-01-40g-radeon-rx-5700-xt-8g-gddr6

Comment: 2)have you tried setting up screens in AMD software? 3)what resolutions have you tried (are you sure each screen supports that resolution); have you tried lowering resolution? 4)have you installing [the latest graphics drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt) (looks like newest is from a couple days ago)? 5)can you a different third screen working?

Comment: My apologies. I bountied this and then had a busy weekend. I believe it is because of the adapters. I bought them before knowing there was such a thing as active adapters. To answer your other questions, I don't see any settings to change resolutions (unless you count scaling)—likely because they are TVs. Honestly, AMD Adrenaline is more confusing and feels like I can do less than the old AMD software in the classic window style. I always check drivers in routine troubleshooting. I don't have a (pin compatible) other monitor to test. Thanks for the followup, everyone.

Comment: Will try to remember to report back after finding some active adapters, to let you all know how it went. No idea what I should even be comparing when shopping for them, tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most issues I had have been with passive adapters.
With 3 displays, I'd use an active adapter.
Also, If you're using docking station...I had a few where only 2 out of 3 outputs are supported at the same time.
I also had to fix issues with 3 displays by reducing the refresh rate just below 60Hz and changing the power settings to use USB 2.0.